# when i was installing this project showing the error in pom.xml file

Tags: java, xml, maven

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-group-call:6.5.0: Failure to find 
 org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-tutorial:pom:6.5.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local 
 repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 
 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>   .........................................showing the error in parent
    <groupId>org.kurento.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>kurento-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>kurento-group-call</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Kurento Java Tutorial - Group Call</name>
<description>WebRTC many to many video call</description>

<url>http://www.kurento.org/docs/${project.version}</url>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>

<organization>
    <name>Kurento</name>
    <url>http://www.kurento.org</url>
</organization>

<scm>
    <url>https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java</url>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git://git@github.com:Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java</developerConnection>
    <tag>develop</tag>
</scm>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>kurento.org</id>
        <name>-kurento.org Community</name>
        <organization>Kurento.org</organization>
        <organizationUrl>http://www.kurento.org</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
</developers>

<properties>
    <demo.port>8086</demo.port>

    <!-- Main class -->
    <start-class>org.kurento.tutorial.groupcall.GroupCallApp</start-class>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Kurento -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kurento</groupId>
        <artifactId>kurento-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kurento</groupId>
        <artifactId>kurento-utils-js</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-bower-install</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>bower</executable>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</workingDirectory>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                            <argument>--allow-root</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/static/bower_components</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.kurento.tutorial</groupId>
            <artifactId>kurentu-group-call</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>banner.txt</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>.</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>bower.json</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <copy
                                        file="${project.build.directory}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-bin.zip"
                                        tofile="${project.build.directory}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip" />
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>no-assembly</id>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that the parent POM `org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-tutorial:pom:6.5.0` cannot be found in the configured repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kurento.tutorial/kurento-group-call, you can see that the version, 6.5.0 that you are trying to download is not available. To fix this problem, navigate to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kurento.tutorial/kurento-group-call and look at the available repository versions and use. You can use it by changing 6.5.0 in the pom.xml file with an available version like 6.11.0